# Create a function called decrypt that takes two parameters, one tuple parameter called key and one string parameter called cipher_text

Tags: python, encryption

> Create a function called decrypt that takes two parameters, one tuple parameter called `key` and one string parameter called `cipher_text`.
>
> The function shall take text in 'cipher text' i.e. coded text and the values of the key in order to shift the text in the appropriate direction.
>
> The function shall return the cipher text as plain text. (Use the `islower()` or `isupper()` function to see if the character is lower or uppercase. Case matters in returning ‘cipher text’).

```
Def decrypt(key, cipher_text):

for i in cipher_text:
       For index in key:
              Text = i + index
text.lower()

return text
```

Comment: You can't have StackOverflow to do your homework for you.

Comment: No I placed the problem so people would understand the context. The code below is my attempted response. I am asking if this is correct and if the for loops I have set up will run the correct indexes correctly

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are looking for - e.g. a specific issue with your code or undesired behavior you do not know how to correct.

Comment: I believe the for loop for the key, I am unsure if the loop inside of the loop is the correct way to call the key. I do not know exactly how to set that up but I believe this is the correct way

Comment: does the cipher text consist of numbers and/ or special characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
def decrypt(key, cipher_text):
    text = str(cipher_text)
    import string
    charup = string.ascii_uppercase
    chardown = string.ascii_lowecase
    newstring = ""
    counter = 0
    for x in text:
        if counter <= len(text) - 1:
           pass
        else:
           counter = 0
        if x.islower():
            newchar = chardown[(chardown.index(x) + key[counter]) % 25]
        elif x.isupper():
            newchar = charup[(charup.index(x) + key[counter]) % 25] 
        newstring = newstring + newchar
        counter = counter + 1
```

While using the following code you need to keep in mind all of the following:

1. I have assumed that the string ***does not*** contain any special character or digit, in which case the `islower()` and `isupper()` won't work.
2. This code will work on **at least** Python 3.3 and Python 3.4
3. I do not know which `appropriate direction` you are talking about.
   If you meant going **backwards** then you only need to change

   ```
   newchar = chardown[(chardown.index(x) + key[counter]) % 25]
   newchar = charup[(charup.index(x) + key[counter]) % 25]
   ```

   to-

   ```
   newchar = chardown[(chardown.index(x) - key[counter]) % 25] 
   newchar = charup[(charup.index(x) + key[counter]) % 25]
   ```

Comment: in the problem you have is key able to be a tuple? Also, I am unsure what is meant by backwards

Comment: For eg: if you shifted A to C then to decrypt it  you need to go backwards from C. Also if the key of yours is a tuple, then you need only do this- `key = list(key)`.  This will convert all the tuples into lists.